# GitHub for Mac: Can't commit and sync or just commit because I have to add files before

Tags: git, github, github-for-mac

I can't commit and sync files from the GitHub for Mac App because the app says that I have to add the files previously, but I want to the app do that for me. I don't want to go to the terminal to `git add -A` every time. My partner can commit and sync and the GitHub for Mac app adds the files for him.

This is the error that the app returns:

```
Git Error:

On branch master Changes not staged for commit: (use "git add ..." to
update what will be committed) (use "git checkout -- ..." to discard
changes in working directory)

modified: .gitignore

... more files here :)

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
(256)
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: I have started having this problem as well. Not sure what's causing it.

Answer (score 1):

So if I understood your problem correctly... You don't want to have the extra step of using `git add` correct? If so, then this is unavoidable with Git. This is a step that's very important, and so completely avoiding it is relatively impossible.

You might want to setup up an alias that does `git commit -a` for you automatically, but really, this step is unavoidable, without either typing it or using an alias.

Also, sorry if this belongs in a comment (can't do comments on the main question for some reason).

Comment: BTW, if this helps, make sure to upvote this answer, and if possible, approve it as an answer. :)

Comment: He's not using `git`, he's using [GitHub for Mac](http://mac.github.com) which is designed to do that stuff for you. If I restart my Mac the app works as it should.

Answer (score -1):

I only fixed this by deleting the

```
~/Library/Application Support/GitHub for Mac/
```

directory and then restarting the app. What  I did was probably overkill, but it worked for me.