# Git error on GitHub for Mac asking me to use terminal to "git add"

Tags: git, github, github-for-mac

While using GitHub for mac, I'm getting the following error box when I try to submit my commit:

```
# On branch Integrating-a-recommendations-textbox
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   modified:   assets/app/scripts/templates/popups/recommend.hbs
#   modified:   web/wgwt/models.py
#   modified:   web/wgwt/views.py
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
 (1)
```

I looked at some other questions, for instance here: [GitHub for Mac: Can't commit and sync or just commit because I have to add files before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11948807/github-for-mac-cant-commit-sync-or-just-commit-because-i-have-to-add-files-b)

But I don't want to use the terminal as a workaround, I want to commit using GitHub for mac. Restarting my machine didn't help. I can see the additions I made to the files in green in the GitHub for Mac changes tab, but can't seem to get past this error. Thanks for any help!

Comment: The message says to use "git add". Did you try that?

Comment: I'm using GitHub for Mac application, so there isn't that option anywhere. I'm following the directions in the GitHub for Mac support documentation. The error message is a little dialogue box that prints out what I expect would be in the terminal, were I using the terminal for the commit.

Comment: Well, I don't use GitHub for Mac specifically, but it looks like this page has the information you need: https://help.github.com/articles/making-changes Perhaps you need to select the file before trying to commit it, or something.

Comment: Thanks - that's the process I'm using. Everything looks the same but the error pops up when I click 'commit'. Some other answers seem to say it's a bug with '.Gitignore' and some ds_store files I had to remove from the commit and that I need to use the terminal to override. Will try that tomorrow if I don't get an answer :/.

Comment: @YPCrumble might be a good time to at least try using the terminal. If you want to become proficient in Git, it's basically a requirement.

Comment: @Cupcake, thanks, that's what I had started to realize, really appreciate your adding the code, big help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that you want to use your GitHub for Mac GUI, but if you were to commit your changes through the terminal instead, here is what you would do:

```bash
# Get the status of your working copy:
$ git status
# On branch Integrating-a-recommendations-textbox
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   modified:   assets/app/scripts/templates/popups/recommend.hbs
#   modified:   web/wgwt/models.py
#   modified:   web/wgwt/views.py
#

# Add each file you want to commit individually:
$ git add web/wgwt/models.py

# Or add them all at once:
$ git add "*"

# Make your commit
$ git commit

# You can also use the `--all` or `-a` flags during the commit
# to add all **tracked/modified** files (but not untracked files)
$ git commit -a

# To push the new commits to a remote repo, use the following:
$ git push <remote-name> head
```

Comment: This worked - I just needed to make sure I was in the proper directory "cd /web/wgwt" and I was able to do it. Also needed to learn a bit of how to get the commit message using "$ git commit -m "Commit message here." and that worked too. Thanks!

Comment: @YPCrumble glad my information was able to help you. If you think my answer deserves it, please also consider upvoting it as well. Also, if you want to learn how to be really good with using Git at the command line, I recommend the [free online Pro Git book](http://git-scm.com/book), chapters 1-3 and 6-6.5. Also make sure you learn how to `rebase` both interactively and non-interactively, you'll probably be using it a lot.